# Why am i getting error in org.apache.jena.query.text?

Tags: lucene, jena

Currently i work with Text Search using Jena and Lucene. I have a problem with Apache Lucene, especially in `org.apache.jena.query.text`. I wrote the import libraries like this:

```
import org.apache.jena.query.text.EntityDefinition;
import org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDatasetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexConfig;
```

Those three libraries says that **cannot be resolved**. I am using Lucene 8.4.0.

What should i do? I think it is because of the version of Lucene but i'm not sure.

Comment: i forget to mention about Jena. I use Jena 3.13.0 too and try with 3.9.0 like the tutorial did. Does that might be a matter too?

Comment: "cannot be resolved" - is that at compile time or at run time? It looks like the jena-text module (and its dependencies, which includes the correct version of Apache Lucene) is not on the compile time/runtime classpath.

Comment: @AndyS just when i enter the libraries, the errors say that

Comment: From the information you've given, the runtime classpath is missing the jena-text artifact which was present when the code was compiled. Check how you are running the code.

Comment: @AndyS it solved! i don't know if it needs one more artifact, which is jena-text. thank you for the helps